# Error: value is not a member of object using Scala on the shell

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark, rdd

Hello I have this scala object and I want to run the code in `sample` function using the shell with scala:

```
object SampleObject{ 
    def sample(){

         val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
         data.foreach(println(_))
    }
}
```

What I do is this

```
scala> :load /Users/username/Desktop/Cli.scala 
Loading /Users/username/Desktop/Cli.scala...
defined object SampleObject
```

But if I run this

```
scala> SampleObject.sample
```

This is what I ge this

```
<console>:92: error: value sample is not a member of object SampleObject
   SampleObject.sample
```

Why does this happen? There's a problem with the commands :load and -i, it's like you can't access to the objects members. Any suggestion to make it work?

**UPDATE1:**
If I run the code above neither doing load or -i but by writing it directly on the shell everything works properly.

**UPDATE2:**
Still not working...
[image]

Comment: Am I right assuming you compile your Scala file before loading it in Spark? By the way, what version of Spark and Scala are you using?

Comment: Works fine for me using `sbt console`

Comment: @asettouf it says "Scala code runner version 2.11.7". Anyway I didn't compile it, I've loaded it and it rightly says "defined object SampleObject" so why can't I access to it's members?

Comment: @radumanolescu lucky you, on my terminal this doesn't work. Wether I call ">scala -i /dir/file.scala" or I do ">scala; >:load /dir/file.scala" it says defined object SampleObject but it doesn't allow me to access to its members anyway.

Comment: Actually my bad, no need to compile. I just made the test with Scala 2.11.8 and Spark 2.1.0 and it works fine. (both with `-i` and `:load`) Meaning there is something else going wrong here. What Spark version do you use? What jdk version are you using as well?

Comment: Wild speculation: do you happen to have another SampleObject class file that you compile previously that could be shadowing the one you loaded? I suppose the loaded one is the one that should shadow, but hey, bugs!

Comment: @pedrofurla you can see from my terminal in the UPDATE2 what I do, it seems correct to me, no?

Comment: @radumanolescu any idea why this is not working? Look at update2. If you think you understood the error, answer to this question so I mark it as a solution.

Comment: @Matt Cannot see images or access chat from my location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that line break before the brace.  You can fix this either of two ways:

1. Use `:paste` instead of `:load`

   Put the brace on the same line as the object name

Your original question said `object SampleObject{` but it turns out that is not what your actual file contains, as your update 2 shows.  Since `:load` works line-by-line, just as if you were typing at the REPL, when the interpreter sees

```
object Cli
```

it's done: that is a perfectly valid, complete Scala declaration of a (not terribly interesting) object.  The opening brace on the next line will start a new block that is unrelated to the object you've just defined.

This is an area where the interactive REPL behaves differently from the compiler, which will allow a single newline before the brace (see [the Scala language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/01-lexical-syntax.html#newline-characters) for specifics).

Comment: Oh that's true! That was my fault too with the question! Thank you so much.